# Why would the centering of an HTML element be affected by the width of its nephew?

Tags: html, css

Here's the basic structure I'm working with

```
<div class="choiceBox">
    <h2>Title</h2>

    <div class="column">
        <h3>Subtitle 1</h3>
        <input type="text">
        <select multiple size="10"></select>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <h3>Subtitle 2</h3>
        <input type="text">
        <select multiple size="10"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The outer div is nowrap, everything (notably the headings) is centered by inheritance, and the inner divs are inline-blocks. JSFiddle of the CSS [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Malnormalulo/1rw6wqee/2/).

There's just one weird thing about it. Originally (as in the JSFiddle above) I had the inputs and selects set to 100% width (by border-box) so that they are always the same width, even if one of them widens. This has the peculiar effect (in Firefox at least) that, when the window is resized to be narrower than the outer div's width, the h2 centers in the window rather than the div. You can see the same thing by shrinking the result frame on the JSFiddle.

This problem goes away by setting min-width instead of width on the select and input, so I do have a solution. But I have no idea why it would behave like this to begin with. Can anyone illuminate this mystery?

EDIT: Ideally, I'd like to know not only why `width: 100%` does foul things up, but also why `min-width: 100%` does not.

Comment: The problem is that, if the window isn't wide enough, the columns overflow `.choiceBox`, but the header won't because it's smaller.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thanks. It doesn't explain though why switching to min-width would fix it (but I suppose technically I didn't ask that). Any ideas there?

Answer (score 1):

It is the combination of the `display: inline-block;` and `white-space: nowrap;` on the `.choiceBox` and the `width: 100%;` of the `.column select, .column input`.

Because of the `display: inline-block;` the `.choiceBox` should be as wide as its content. But with the `white-space: nowrap;` the `width: 100%;` is no longer enough to expand the `div` and it shrinks with the viewport. See: http://jsfiddle.net/1rw6wqee/3/

If I have to pick one, I would say the `white-space: nowrap;` is the bad guy here.

Comment: Well illustrated, thanks. But why would `min-width: 100%` expand the div when `width: 100%` does not? The input and select seem to be no more than 100% the width of their parent either way.

Comment: Basically, `min-width` is more restrictive than `width`. So `width: 100%` would read like "try to be as large as your parent" while `min-width:100%` would read like "do not be smaller than your parent". A good trick for all browsers would be to use both `width:100%; min-width:100%;` (if you can afford the extra markups).